# Android MVP взаимодействие view и presenter

Tags: java, android, mvp

Прочитав статьи и просмотрев прилагающейся к ним код, так и не понял как правильно организовать взаимодействие view и presenter. Основная идея в том что presenter получает событие от view и реагирует на него. Т.е. нажата кнопка поиска в presenter передается событие onSearchButtonClicked и presenter загружает данные. Или Activity (View) создалась в presenter передается событие OnCreate выполняется загрузка данных. Можно ли выполнять метод presenter`a loadData() напрямую из view, а не передать сперва событые в отдельный метод presenter`a и потом уже в presenter`е вызвать loadData()?

Первый вариант

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Presenter presenter = new Presenter();

    @Override
    void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        presenter.onCreate();
    }
}

class Presenter {
    void loadData() {
        // load something
    }

    void onCreate() {
        loadData();
    }
}
```

Второй вариант

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Presenter presenter = new Presenter();

    @Override
    void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        presenter.loadData();
    }
}

class Presenter {
    void loadData() {
        // load something
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно и так и так. Событийная модель может быть однородной в том плане, что представление общается с презентером исключительно с помощью событий, а не вперемешку с "бизнесс"-методами.

Answer (score 0):

В Android используется подход "Слабая" View. Она уведомляет Presenter о случившемся событии : каждое действие пользователя передаётся в Presenter в качестве события.

В вашем случае более верным является первый вариант, однако его можно модифицировать:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tvName;

    Presenter presenter = new Presenter();

    @Override
    void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Find views...

        presenter.viewCreated();

        tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void click(View view) {
                presenter.nameClicked();
            }
        }

    }
}

class Presenter {

    void viewCreated() {
        loadData()
    }

    private void loadData() {
       // Do smth
    }

    void nameClicked() {
        // Do smth
    }
}
```